# how to create a for loop with a drop down box

Tags: javascript, php, sql, arrays, loops

Hi I am trying to create a set of drop down boxes that will use an array of data from the values that you pick and then runs through a loop to post them to the screen at the moment the  data that i want to use will just be local but i want to edit this later so that it will loop through the data from my database and post that to the screen. i have looked at other questions on this subject and just wondering how i would change it for my code i have looked at this link [questions on stack overflow that I have looked at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754087/how-to-create-a-loop-for-this-dropdown-menu) i have just got a couple questions that im wondering if anybody has seen this before or if they have seen any examples i have also looked at for loops and i understand the concept

my questions to you are:

1) how would I post the values from my drop down boxes into a php array
2) how would I then check the values against and array of data and then choose which are correct and post them to the screen.
3)Would I need to use a second language like javascript or can it be done just in php

My drop down box code is

```
<div id="Content">

    <?php include "select.class.php"; ?>
    <form id="select_form">
        Choose a category:<br />
        <select id="category">
            <?php echo $opt->ShowCategory(); ?>
        </select>
        <br /><br />

        Choose a type:<br />
        <select id="type">
            <option value="%">any...</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />

        Choose a principle:<br />
        <select id="principle">
            <option value="%">any...</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="confirm" />
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>

    <!-- end of the Options -->
```

below is the select.class.php

```
<?php
    class SelectList
    {
        protected $conn;

            public function __construct()
            {
                $this->DbConnect();
            }

            protected function DbConnect()
            {
                include "db_config.php";
                $this->conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR die("Unable to connect to the database");
                mysql_select_db($db,$this->conn) OR die("can not select the database $db");
                return TRUE;
            }

            public function ShowCategory()
            {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM subject";
                $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
                $category = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
                {
                    $category .= '<option value="' . $row['subject_id'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</option>';
                }
                return $category;
            }

            public function ShowType()
            {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM section WHERE subject_id=$_POST[id]";
                $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
                $type = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
                {
                    $type .= '<option value="' . $row['section_id'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</option>';
                }
                return $type;
            }

             public function ShowPrinciple()
            {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM principle WHERE section_id=$_POST[id]";
                $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
                $principle = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
                {
                    $principle .= '<option value="' . $row['principle_id'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</option>';
                }
                return $principle;
            }   
    }

    $opt = new SelectList();
?>
```

Comment: could you post the code for `select.class.php` and also `$opt->ShowCategory();`

Comment: Are you looking for the value of the first select list to then filter/populate the options of the second select list?

Comment: the drop down boxes populate each other with from the option from the first @AlexP this is working im trying to search an array from the values of each of these drop down boxes

Comment: @anurupr I have added the code from the select.class.php

Comment: instead of returning a string from `ShowCategory()` you could return an array which you can pass to another function and use `array_search` to check the correct values

Comment: @anurupr would you mind showing me a code example of how to do this cause I don't have much experience with arrays

Comment: it would be too lengthy to post as a comment

Comment: could you post as an answer @anurupr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) how would I post the values from my drop down boxes into a php array

In the form tag add method="POST". Reference in PHP with $_POST array. Make sure to validate and escape the data before writing to your DB.

> 2) how would I then check the values against and array of data and then choose which are correct and post them to the screen.

If you don't have millions of categories, you are better off sending them all as a JSON array and using Javascript. Something like:

```
<script>
var categories = <?php echo json_encode($opt->ShowCategory()); ?>;
</script>
```

json_encode may require some options to be set, depening on your character set. More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Making a new request each time someone changes a dropdown box will drive them crazy, I know I hate that. If you have used jQuery before, this is very easy. This isn't that difficult without it.

> 3)Would I need to use a second language like javascript or can it be done just in php

For the sake of your users, use Javascript.

Comment: would you mind showing me how to do this because i understand what i should do but everytime i try it breaks the page

Comment: Sure, put up a pastebin of what you have. My post uses opt->ShowCategory(), now seeing what that code does, that function would require some changes.

Comment: Ok, see below: http://pastebin.com/hv8t3C0u
http://pastebin.com/n3yzqjQ8
I have just shown you an example of what I mean. I have not been able to test it, so may be typos etc. You should do the same for section then principle, just load them all and use JS to filter it depending on what the user selects in the category.

Answer (score 0):

code for showCategory()

```
...
$categories = new array();
$category = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $categories[$row['subject_id']] = $row['description'];
            }
$validCategories = $this->getValidCategories() // get the valid categories 
foreach($categories as $index=>$cat){
   // only choose the categories that are valid
   if(array_search($cat,$validCategories) !== FALSE)
       $category.= '<option value="'.$index.'">'.$cat.'</option>'; 

}
return $category;
```

Comment: it would be preferable to get the valid categories from the db and populate it there but this should do what you had asked

Comment: I have added this into the page and it breaks the page, the section where the drop down boxes are everything goes. any ideas

Comment: did you add the function `validCategories` to your class ?

Comment: where would I add this ?

Comment: in your `select.class.php` . write a query to get the valid categories.

Comment: the sql query for the catergory is already in my select.class.php would i need to change this in any way

Comment: if you have the valid categories in a different table then it wouldnt be required. but if you're having all the categories in a single table you will need to modify the query and there would be no need to use `array_search` for that

Comment: i will have 3 tables of information one for subjects one for the sections and one for the principles this is because there are three drop down menus in the code above

Comment: then you will need to add some logic to find out the valid categories

Comment: What does this mean ?

Comment: you could add a where clause in your query which satisfies the valid category condition according to your application